# Can i access c++ or Java functions inside python

Tags: java, c++, python, linux

I am mainly using python for extensive algorithms operations. Now i have my webiste in Django.

I few libraries in c++ and few in Java which i don't have in python. Or you can say that i already have some c++ , Java files in which some algorithm is coded.

can i call those function or do some calculation in my djnago sites using those c++ or java files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++, certainly. Either [write a module](http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html) that wraps the library, or use something like ctypes or SWIG.

For Java, you'd be best to move to Jython (and correspondingly use django-jython).

Note that using both C++ *and* Java from Python is *not* trivial.

Comment: sorry but my english is not so good so u mean not trivial means not easy means difficult. So u mean people r not using it

Comment: It takes a decent amount of both knowledge and skill to be able to bridge C++, Java, and Python.

Comment: It might be possible to compile the Java code to native library with gjc and use the C method on it, but even if the library actually compiles, it would still be hard.

Comment: ok , but i will not be using it initially , i was just asking if thats possible or not. Actuaaly i want to implement Genetic algiriths and optimaztion algos in python , i have books in java and c++ which explains the code and working but not in python. so i thought i need arises i can bridge them. there are libraries in python as well but i want to code myself

Comment: The only way for a novice to get this working is to use Jython instead of Python to call Java methods. As long as you don't have the Java code (but only the text in the book) I suggest to simply rewrite it in Python. That should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the http://www.scipy.org/Weave weave package for C/C++. I didn't use it myself, but I know it exists

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) to some degree of success for accessing C++ libraries within Python/Django.